# Fast Mouseenter/Mouseleave messes up animation

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave, mousehover

Another fast mouse hover animation problem.

I've got 3 hoverable divs that return html() text when hovered - HTML:

```
<div id="hoverableDivs_container" class="hoverableDiv">
    <div id="hoverableDiv1" class="hoverableDiv"><p>Hoverable<br>div 1</p></div>
    <div id="hoverableDiv2" class="hoverableDiv"><p>Hoverable<br>div 2</p></div>
    <div id="hoverableDiv3" class="hoverableDiv"><p>Hoverable<br>div 3</p></div>
</div>

<div id="infoBox">
    <p>InfoBOX</p>
    <div id="infoBox_inactive"></div>
    <div id="infoBox_active"></div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XW7tY/).

If I:

- fast mouseenter/mouseleave the hoverable divs it gets all messed up.
- hover from one div to the other it gets all messed up

I've tried **stop()** in every imaginable way, but can't get it to work properly (I removed the stop()s for now).

The only way it works is to mouseenter/mouseleave slowly, in the same div (in and out and back in).

Help, please.

Pedro

Answer (score 1):

Use `.stop()` method before every animate method. If it is called on an element, the currently-running animation (if any) is immediately stopped.

See the work [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wG4Pp/) here.

For better optimised code, Try removing `.stop()` and see where it get messed up and leave where it required. I have added `.stop` before animation method for the sake of easiness.

Comment: Still not ok. If you mouseenter/mouseleave quickly, the last text and the yellow bg remain - I want it to go back to the default aspect (black bg and "infoBox" text).

Comment: that could be done but you would have to change the code accordingly. I was only focusing on the animation issue you had.